# Difference between Data Mapper Mediator and Payload Factory Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Besides the syntax what is the core difference between a data mapper and payload factory? They both can convert/transform data from one format to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the data mapper only a few times (you stick with what you know). In my opinion both mediators provide mostly the same functionality (as does the xslt mediator) but the underlying technology and mainly the development method is radically different.

- **datamapper** provides a graphical way of transforming messages. It uses
  existing output and input messages to seed the transformation so it is strong when you have the output of service A and the input of service B and just need to map the data from A to B.
- **payloadFactory** is able to quickly build messages. I use it mostly to create requests where only a few fields need to be mapped from the original request to the new request.
- **xslt** is a versatile and powerful way of transforming messages but it requires some experience. A lot of 3th party tooling is available to assist with the transformation.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Comment: Another difference is speed btw: https://www.yenlo.com/blog/transforming-messages-inside-wso2-esb-5.0.0 Note that datamapper was quite new when this blog came out so the technology might have improved in the meantime.