# how to achieve working of javascript's 'JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(keyName)' function in WSO2 DataMapper

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO EI 6.5 Data Mapper Mediator to perform a message transformation. The input message of the Mapper has two parts. Part one has a 'name' key and value of this key is the key in itself on the part two of the message.

Example

```
{
    "part1": {
        "name": "abc"
    },
    "part2": {
        "abc": 123,
        "pqr": 987,
        "xyz": 776
}
```

What I want to achieve is get the value '123' returned as output of transformation in the above example. 
In javascript, we can do this using

```
if(part2.hasOwnProperty(part1.name)) {
    var value = part2[part1.name];
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using WSO2 EI 6.5 Data Mapper Mediator.

Comment: Datamapper transforms a message into a different message, so there is no '123' output possible. Perhaps this helps in understanding the datamapper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650230/difference-between-data-mapper-mediator-and-payload-factory-mediator

Comment: Agreed. I realized it and hence modified the flow to use PayloadFactory and XSLT to achieve my results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a custom class mediator.
Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Class+Mediator

Comment: Actually, I was hoping to have this readily available in DataMapper. using a custom class mediator would mean there is potenitally no need for using Data Mapper as I can do complete transformation in my class. The idea was to avoid writing any code and just use the default mediators provided by WSO2 EI.
I eventually resorted to combination of PayLoadFactory and XSLT transformation to achieve my need.

Comment: Yes, you can do it using XSLT mediator